# A setup package is either missing or damaged - Visual Studio 2015 on Win 7

Tags: visual-studio, windows-7

[image: Screenshot of Installer]

This problem only started to happen recently when trying to install/repair Visual Studio 2015.

"A setup package is either missing or damaged" and the package being something along the lines of `Win10_UniversalCRTSDK\Universal CRT Headers Libraries and Sources-x86_en-us.msi`

Does anyone know how to fix this error?

EDIT: My current solution was to skip the package, not sure if I will need it later though, and how will I install it later?

Comment: exactly same problem here; maybe this helps: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d91793ca-c63a-451a-a3b6-0430939e749d/vs-2015-express-setup-package-is-either-missing-or-damaged-vcredistx64exe?forum=vssetup

Comment: Did you use an old installer and not a fresh one of microsoft's homepage? I did and I will try fresh installer. And I'm using Enterprise Version!